# Problem working with jQuery

Tags: jquery

jQuery for some reason isn't working.I'd like to know what the problem is.Here is my code :

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script language="text/javascript">
function hide() {
    $("#Layer1").hide("fast");
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
 background-color: #000000;
}
#Layer1 {
 position:absolute;
 width:200px;
 height:115px;
 z-index:1;
 left: 179px;
 top: 3px;
}
#Layer2 {
 position:absolute;
 width:101px;
 height:80px;
 z-index:2;
 left: 570px;
 top: 473px;
}
-->
</style></head>
<body>
<div id="Layer1"></div>
<div id="Layer2" onclick="hide()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Which part isn't working? Here's your code, seems to do what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/58RU5/

Comment: What is the expected behavior you're not seeing?

Comment: it probably isn't the problem, but you should use `<script type="text/javascript">`, and not "language" attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the form of the `script` tag that goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

with the one that goes:

```
<script language="javascript">
```

(see e.g. [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/languageattri.shtml) for some explanation).  Why not fix your tags to use just `type=` instead?  Not sure whether that's all your problem (after spotting this one I think it needs to be fixed even if there were others;-) but it's confusing *me* and could be confusing your browser;-).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's the problem, but trying changing your function name from `hide()`, which is a jQuery function, to something else like `hideDiv()`

Since `hide()` isn't being used with the jQuery tag `($.hide())` I doubt this is the issue, but worth a shot I guess.